# Elasticsearch:How to fetch all the records with most recent entry at first

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

How can i get all the records from elasticsearch with most recent entry as the first record

for example,

If i have 5 libraries with ids from 1 to 5,
how can i get complete list of books from library 5 which is sorted with latest book entered.

Here is my sample query which consisting of nested fields

```
http://localhost:9200/library*/_search

 {
            "size": 1000,
            "_source": [

               "library.bookname","library.author"
            ],
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "library.id": 5
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It depends how you define 'latest' - do you have a timestamp field or similar in your document mapping? If so, sort on that field. If not, you can't.

Comment: Should i add timestamp as a field in elasticsearch for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sort option in the request body](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/search-request-sort.html). If you want to sort it by the latest book entered, there is an `order` option that should be set to `desc`. For this, you need to have a timestamp field or a similar one that can be sorted by the order it entered.
Lets say you have a date field `timestamp` and it will be used for sorting by the latest entered, then you can do something like this to sort the result:
`"sort": { "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } }`.
So, your sample query will look like:

```
http://localhost:9200/library*/_search

 {
            "size": 1000,
            "sort": { "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } },
            "_source": [

               "library.bookname","library.author"
            ],
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "library.id": 5
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is capable of fetching only 1000 entries, if i have 10000 entries this fails....How the query should  look like if i need the whole entries?

Comment: @ashfak You can use scroll api for this feature https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html